# Ask a Telnet server to ignore commands

Tags: c, sockets, connection, telnet

Let's say I have a working Telnet server and client; the client is my own C-programmed creation, though the server is not under my control (in my case, it is a Perle Systems IOLAN SCS48, but it could be any RFC2217-enabled Telnet device).

I want to use the devices serial tunneling features (via the RFC 2217 protocol for Telnet), but only at the start of the connection. As such, I receive four negotiation requests from the server (`WILL TRANSMIT-BINARY`, `DO TRANSMIT-BINARY`, `WILL ECHO`, `DO SUPPRESS-GO-AHEAD`, `WILL SUPPRESS-GO-AHEAD` and `DO COM-PORT-OPTION`; the last one being from RFC 2217), to all of which I respond, and then set baudrate, datasize, parity bit and stop bit.

So far so good, but now I want to re-arrange the communication so the server ignores all future commands (especiall the `IAC` character `0x255`), so I can pass Hex-converted strings through the device to the receiving end (connected to the device's serial port), which gets every single byte I send (and not lose three bytes for every 0x255 that is somewhere in my string, or seven bytes where there is `0x255 0x250` (`IAC SB`)).

Alternatively, would there be a possibility to make the server pass an escaped escape char (two 0x255's in a row, which are then printed as-input) as a single 0x255?

I do not want to close the connection to reopen it is a raw one, as my serial settings would be lost (because that's how the device's COM port redirection works, I suppose). However, I do not need to re-establish command listening, so the connection can simply be closed and reopened as another Telnet connection if I need to reconfigure the baudrate.

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a standard IAC DO IGNORE-FURTHER-IACS, I've never heard of it.

[RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) does not explain this very well, but the documented meaning of two IACs in a row is "data byte 255", so I think the server is *already* supposed to pass 0x255 0x255 onward as a single 0x255. Is it not doing that?

Comment: Truly the wording is not quite the clearest; it does say that "only the IAC need be doubled to be sent as data", and I also see (if I connect two ports using a null modem cable and hook a PuTTY session into the second port's ethernet connection) that I get two unreadable characters (presumably 0x255 and 0x255) when passing IAC twice in a row.

Comment: I would be looking into this as a bug in the server-side telnet implementation.  You should find out exactly what those two characters are.  You should also experiment with sending e.g. 255 255 246 (escaped IAC AYT) or 255 255 253 001 (escaped IAC DO ECHO) and see if they are interpreted as commands.  And finally, have a look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc856 : putting the telnet channel in "binary mode" may help with this scenario.

Comment: I cannot influence the serverside implementation, unfortunately. I have hooked up my own client to the other side and had it print the character codes, and truly, I received 255 255 plainly upon sending those. Testing your escaped examples, everything is passed through unexecuted, as it should be. Checking the requested RFC 856, I saw that binary transmission, code 0, is one of the negotiations handeled. Thus, I swapped my WONT for a WILL, however, it doesn't seem to have changed anything; IAC is still intrepreted, and two IACs turn out as two IACs.

Comment: I don't see anything unclear about it. IAC needs to be escaped if present in data. This is not a mystery.

Comment: @Prols1981 With the escaped commands, they're not executed, but do they come through to the far side with the IAC still doubled?

Comment: Well yeah, whatever escaped command there is, if it is preceeded by 255 255, the other side will print 255 255 first and then everything else you entered. I don't see why succeeding characters would change what had been printed before-hand.

Comment: The bug -- and I'm convinced it _is_ a bug at this point -- might only have affected _incomplete_ control sequences with a double IAC at the beginning.  (So, like, 255 255 246 would come through as 255 246, but 255 255 020 would keep both 255's.)

Comment: It might just be a faulty serverside implementation, but as already stated I am completely unable to do anything about that, which is a bummer. Appreciate the help, though!